# Where is the implementation of `Index::index`

Tags: rust

I was tracking the Rust's standard library's implementation for `Vec<T>`'s Indexing, that is, `myvec[n]`. If I was correct, [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2731) should be the source.

But it in turn calls `Index::index(...)`, of which I currently cannot find the definition, could anyone give some clues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It refers to the implementation of Index for slice &[T] edit: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/index.rs.html#10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&**` operators cause delegation to [`[T]`'s `Index` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/index.rs.html#10) by way of [`Vec`'s `Deref` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref-for-Vec%3CT%2C%20A%3E).  This implementation requires the argument to be something implementing the [`SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html) trait, which defines both how the index operation is performed as well as the produced result type (e.g. ranges produce slices, while `usize` produces an `Option<&T>`).

To clarify, note that `Index::index()` is the *very same trait method you're looking at.*  It appears to be a recursive call at first glance, but since `&**self` is not the same type, it causes a different `Index` implementation to be used (`[T]`'s instead of `Vec<T>`'s) and so it's not actually recursive.

Comment: Though `ops::Index<I> for [T]` appears to be the next one in the interesting calling chain, I think, `SliceIndex<[T]> for usize`([src](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/index.rs.html#257)) is the actual one that I was looking for. Thanks for the hint, it helps a lot!

Comment: Another new confusion arises... Why standard library here choose `&**`, rather than just `**`?

Comment: @absuu because ** would result in a bare unsized [T] which can not be placed on the stack.

Comment: First * derefs &Vec to Vec, next one goes through Deref to [T], then that is borrowed, giving & [T]